# Возврат значения из функции которая является аргументом для другой функции

Tags: javascript, функции, асинхронность

```
function GetSqlResponce(sqlQuery : string): object{
    connection.query(sqlQuery, function(err : object, results : object){
        if(err) return err;
        else return results;
    }
}
```

пишет ошибку что функция `GetSqlResponce` ничего не возвращает. Как мне получить значения `err` и `results` из функции? Я пытался сменить функцию в аргументе для `connection.query` на лямбда-функцию, но ошибка осталась.

Comment: Перед `connection.query` добавьте **return**

Comment: Если не поможет, то оберните в промис

Comment: connection.query() возвращает Query{},  как правильно обернуть это в промис?

Answer (score 1):

Можно обернуть метод **connection.query** в промис:

```
function GetSqlResponce(sqlQuery: string): object {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sqlQuery, function (err: object, results: object) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(results);
    }
  })

}

GetSqlResponce('select * from table1')
  .then(res => {
    // Код, если успешно
  })
  .catch(rej => {
    // Если произошла ошибка
  })
```

Comment: Разве тут `if (err) reject(err);` return не нужен?